# I don't know how to fix it. About the MRTK's NearInteractionGrabbable

Tags: c, unity-game-engine, mrtk

I have a HoloLens 2, then I created one test project in Unity3D and put into my HoloLens 2, but I found a serious problem and I don't know how to fix it. This is the error that I found:

NearInteractionGrabbable requires a BoxCollider, SphereCollider, CapsuleCollider or a convex MeshCollider on an object. Otherwise grab interaction will not work correctly.

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)

This error cause my object in HoloLens 2 cannot grab and move it, but the most important point is that I have already set the BoxCollider on my 3D object. I really don't know how to fix this problem......

I have already goto the NearInteractionGrabbable.cs and try to Debug.Log the Collider's list, it didn't have anything, is null, but I pretty sure I have set the BoxCollider on my 3D object, and "istrigger" is ticked. Does anyone have the solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hey:) Let's see if we can help you. So is there a mesh/box/whatever collider on the same object that you put the near interaction grabbable script on?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Collider component is on the same GameObject as the NearInteractionGrabbable component.
Also, make sure the attached collider is either a BoxCollider, CapsuleCollider, SphereCollider, or MeshCollider. If it is a MeshCollider, you'll need to set the `convex` property to true.

Without further information, it is hard to help you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure the Collider component is on the same GameObject as the NearInteractionGrabbable component. I have try to build a new project same as this one, and it's amazing that it didn't have that error.